# Staying at list item interface after editing

Tags: sharepoint-server

We are using Sharepoint server 2019 (on premise).
We would like to stay at list item's interface after editing it (and pressing OK to save). Is there any setting to enable that or any workaround to do?
In current way, Sharepoint will close item view and switch to list view.

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following JavaScript code into a Script Editor web part in EditForm page.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){    
var button = $("input[id$='SaveItem']");     
button.removeAttr("onclick");
    button.val("Apply");
button.click(function() {
    var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
    var aspForm = $("form[id='aspnetForm']");
    var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action;
    var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
    var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, encodeURIComponent(window.location.href));

    if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
    WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
});
});
</script>
```

See my test result in this original post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1167768/staying-at-list-item-interface-after-editing.